# Lotus Notes, button click attach file instead attach file from menu

Tags: lotus-notes

How to call attach file with button click instead of attach via File-> Attach? I had search through google and can't seen to find a way to make it, is it possible to attach via button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, find the answer, just put in the following command to make it work
@Command([EditGotoField]; "Control name");
@Command( [EditInsertFileAttachment] )